# how to fix expansion panel margin issue

Tags: html, css, angular, types, styles

I show my backend data using expansion panel but some reason the margin is very weird, some look like they are almost touching each other and some look like they are further apart from other.

I don't have any styling other than margin-bottom: 1px so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help on how I can fix this to make it look nice and make the margin to be all the same.

```
                <mat-nav-list>
                    <mat-expansion-panel class="exp-panel" *ngFor="let section of mappedSecSub | async">
                        <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="section.parentId == null" style="align-items: center;">
                            <div>{{section.name}}</div>
                        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <div *ngFor="let subSection of mappedSecSub | async; let last=last">
                            <div *ngIf="subSection.parentId == section.id;" (click)="clicked(subSection.id)">
                                <a mat-list-item>{{subSection.name}}
                                    <mat-divider *ngIf="!last" class="solid"></mat-divider>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                </mat-nav-list>
```

```
.exp-panel {
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

```
mappedSecSub = this.mappedSections.asObservable()

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    this.loading = true;
    this.HelpService.getHelp().subscribe(res => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.cdRefs.detectChanges()
      this.mappedSections.next(res['res'])
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.data && this.data.needToScroll) {
          this.scrollToLast()
        }
      }, 1000)
      this.allData = res['res']
    }, () => this.loading = false)
  }
```

The margin look like it is random. they don't have the same margin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe there are empty rows in your data and when you iterate over them, they just add those 1px margins

Comment: I don't think I have any empty row in my data, also if I remove 1px then they all touch each other. out of idea now on how I can make the margin the same for all of them :(

Comment: Can you post the raw data that generates this panel?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by raw data that generate this panel, I basically do api call to my database and display the data using that expansion panel.

Comment: I mean the data comes from your api

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the image and not sure if that is what you mean but can you please check it out for me. thanks

Comment: It looks like the more subitems a section has, the more bottom margin it has. For example,

Comment: hmmm.. could be but I don't know if that make sense. Any idea how I should fix that?

Comment: I’m not very familiar with Angular sorry